# Is there a way to pause a test and let the user control mouse and keyboard in Playwright?

Tags: playwright

Using automated end-to-end testing tool [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/), I want to pause a test, take over the mouse and type something on the screen or click on something, and then resume the test.

Is there a way to do this? Is there a Playwright command that lets me enter input?

Comment: You can refer to this https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-pause